# How can I share the same database connection instance between different modules in a package?

Tags: python

I have a number of modules that needs to have a database connection instance, and I would prefer they share the same instance and don't create their own. My current way of doing this is to explicitly send each function in all modules the object instance like such:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, database_connection):
    pass
```

This becomes quite ugly and in a way redundant when there should be a better way to import a separate module containing the instance, but I'm not quite sure how to guarantee that it's actually one single instance, and not multiple instances.

That is, I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
import db_module
def func(arg1, arg2):
    database_connection = db_module.get_db_instance()
```

Comment: Look for singleton pattern for python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you've described:

```
import db_module
def func(arg1, arg2):
    database_connection = db_module.get_db_instance()
```

is perfectly viable because Python imports each module exactly once. If multiple `import` statements are executed, they each refer to a single instance of the module.

You can read more about modules and importing in the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules) and the
[Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).

Comment: Is this also true when importing from different modules within the same package? This is what I was mostly worried about.

Comment: Yes. Regardless of where the import is *from*, a single module is only ever instantiated once.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? Create a module that imports the defined function?

db_module.py
my_connection = func(x,y)

from db_module import my_connection